# GITHUB Pushing files from different directories

Tags: git, github

I have a problem in github.
I have a repository called `Hackerrank` and i have a project file with sub packages in eclipse to upload this repository.

Also, in `pycharm` i have a project with same name including sub packages.

What i want to do is, uploading new files from both workspace of `eclipse` and `pycharm`.
I created connections in these directories

for Eclipse files: ../workspace/Hackerrank/Algorithm/

for Pycharm files: ../Pycharm/Hackerrank/Algorithm/

When i upload just one of them there is no problem.
When i upload one after another, the older files are deleted.

Can you help me please to solve this problem?
Thank you

Comment: What do you see when you open console and view the log? `git log --cc` on git >2.6

Answer (score 0):

Put both code bases in the same directory. Something like

```
.../hackerrrankrepo/src/python/hackerrank/algorithm
.../hackerrrankrepo/src/java/hackerrank/algorithm
```

You don't need to let your chosen editor influence your project file structure. Make your editor work the way you want: editors are configurable. Your build system (e.g. maven) might be less configurable, so take what you need from that and make it work with your editors.

Comment: Im doing all pushing thing from terminal not from eclipse or pycharm itself. As i see, you seperated directories as ./java and ./python is there any way to push in the same directory on terminal

Comment: You can push from one to your origin, then pull from origin to a new location, then copy all your other editor's stuff into there, then push from there to origin, then pull back to your first location.  All synced now. However: don't do that. Keep your codebases separate and under a common project directory.